# What is the best way to add 2 jokers in a deck of cards?

Tags: python

So for non-card players, a deck is usually comprised of 52 cards (4 suits with 13 ranks each). But for the deck I am creating, I want to include 2 jokers that are of equal rank (I will be calling them Black Joker and Red Joker for this case) that will have a higher rank than the 13 ranks, making the total number of cards to 54 and the total ranks technically 14.

So this is the most common solution I found to making a deck of cards (without the jokers):

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        for s in ["Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"]:
            for v in range (1, 14):
                self.cards.append(Card(s, v))
```

I would like to know if there is a way to add the jokers in this while still being able to insert them in shuffles. I'm still fairly new to Python so an explanation would be really helpful.

Comment: you should probably understand how your data is being stored in the first place if you dont know how to create and add a couple objects to a list...

Comment: This is not a deck, its a card definition.. what exactly do you want?

Comment: There are no constraints to the kind of value you can add to a list data structure in python. So for Queen 'Q', King 'K' and similarly for a redjoker you can have 'RJ' You get the gist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that you dont know what you're actually doing w/ this so let me first explain it...

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value
```

Given this class, you initiate an object with 2 attributes: `suit` and `value`

So to properly define something like a joker you could do the following:

```
>>> joker = Card("Hearts", "J")
>>> joker.suit # get the suit
Hearts
>>> joker.value # get the value
J
```

assuming you have a deck of cards in a list you can just append this:

```
deck.append(Card('Hearts', 'J'))
```

so lets see how this can be implemented with your updated code:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        for s in ["Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"]:
            for v in range (1, 14):
                self.cards.append(Card(s, v))

cardDeck = Deck()
cardDeck.cards.append(Card("Suit", "Joker")) #maybe use 0 as joker value? depends on what you're doing
# add a card to the end

print(cardDeck.cards[-1].value) # print last element's value of the card deck
```

**output**

```
Joker
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing any kind of type checking or any other constraints on suit or value in the example, so what's to stop you from doing something like this?

```
deck = [Card(suit, value) for suit in '♠♣♥♦' for value in 'A23456789XJQK']
deck.append(Card('black', 'joker'))
deck.append(Card('red', 'joker'))
```

Comment: then you should maybe get the basics down, look into `classes` and *maybe* dont skid code for bigger projects if you dont know how to use it.

Comment: if this helped you might want to [accept @gilch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)